# Why can't I just declare the script in <head>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I de-comment in the HTML, the code works properly. May I ask what the problem is and why it happened? Just started learning web programming last week, thanks a lot.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Canvas</title>
        <script src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
        <script src="menu.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <span id="id1">Welcome back to my site. </span>
        <div id="div1" >
            <p>Hi</p>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="hyper">Hi</a>
            <!--<script src="menu.js"></script> -->
        </div>
        <input type="button" id="btn" value="Toggle" />

    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript (menu.js)

```
$("#hyper").click(function(){
    alert("Hi");
});
```

Comment: Maybe because the script will be loaded before the actual button that will trigger the function, and by that time the id "hyper" is not yet existing?

Comment: wrap in jqueries be-all-end-all solution-to-almost-everything ... the *document ready*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when the `<script>` is in `<head>` its executed before the document has been loaded. It means when the `<script>` is in `<head>` and `$("#hyper")` line is executed at that time the element

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="hyper">Hi</a>
```

is not generated. So it doesnot work.

**Solution**:

- Put your `<script>` at end of `<body>`
- Or you can use `document.ready()`

Below are two examples to see the difference.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  //At this point "<div id="test"><div>" is not loaded 
  console.log($('#test').length) //0
  console.log(document.querySelector('#test')) //null
</script>

<div id="test"><div>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test"><div>

<script>
  console.log($('#test').length) //1
  console.log(document.querySelector('#test')) //<div id="test">…</div>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That happened to me once, and it was resolved after I declared the script at the end of <body>. Now I understood why.

Comment: @TngJunWei Accept the answer if you are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with scripts in the `<head>`

1. Those scripts are executed before loading of the body, sometimes this may cause problems, however you can overcome this problem using `document.ready` or `window.onload` etc.
2. In big applications scripts become very big file, then if you've loaded them in the `<head>`, then user have to wait until they load fully to see anything on the webpage, but if you put them in the footer of the page, then you can create a pre-loader on the webpage, which will be loaded and shown to the user until all the scripts load completely.